# Site not visible from public address

Tags: webserver

Good evening,

I created a page on my local gnu/linux machine and created a port forwarding record on my router to make the page visible from public address. And it is visible via localhost and public IP, but only from LAN ... when I try to connect to a site from a different network it is not possible. I thought I made the setup ok but something seems wrong.
I even disabled firewall.
Any idea what happened?

Comment: Your ISP may be blocking incoming connections. Maybe it will work on non-standard port. Try port forwarding your website to some non-standard port number and check if website will work on that port.

Comment: "*it is visible via localhost and public IP, but only from LAN*" That usually happens to folks who confuse their LAN IP address with the router's (public) IP address. Unless you have a fancy router, using the router (public/external) IP address *inside the LAN* usually won't resolve, since it's an invalid address for that subnet.

Comment: I don't understand. I have IPv4 WAN address, added even domain name. I can use  local LAN IP, WAN address (port forwarded) and even domain name from provider but only inside my network.

Comment: Have you used a tool like https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ to check if your port is open?